# Close Rqt Plugin from a button

Tags: plugin, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I want to know how I can close my rqt plugin when I push a button on it.

I tried with exit(0) but it close the plugin like if it was an error in a thread (My plugin doesn't use threads) and the last thing I tried was widget.close() but this one close the widget but rqt main window continues running.

I will appreciate any help.Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255562/close-rqt-plugin-from-a-button/) by [Kuro9206](https://answers.ros.org/users/20547/kuro9206/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to try calling the method [shutdown_plugin](https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/blob/4568b4c7cc13009f4034a8335f15129c498d1548/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin.py#L46) on the plugin instance.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kuro9206](https://answers.ros.org/users/20547/kuro9206/) on 2017-02-24**:
Hello Dirk Thomas
I connect the button with shutdown_plugin() but it doesn't work. Freeze the plugin and seconds later the terminal show the following [FATAL] [1487975743.765361534]: ASSERTION FAILED
file = /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/publisher.h
line = 102
cond = false
message = [FATAL] [..]..

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-02-24**:
Since the error message is truncated I can't say much but it looks a lot like that your plugin is actually trying to close but does something wrong during that. Maybe it doesn't close all handles correctly?

**Comment by [Kuro9206](https://answers.ros.org/users/20547/kuro9206/) on 2017-02-27**:
Hello  Dirk Thomas, I remove the subscribers in the shutdown function and it works.
Thank you for your help

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-02-27**:
Great, please mark the answer as "correct" so that others can easily find the question / answer.